# Ruby on Rails: Having trouble adding a description to blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

In my Rails app all posts are displayed on the index page. Only the title of posts and the date it was published are displayed on the index page. For example, if you click a post, you will be taken to `localhost:3000/posts/1` where you can see the title, date, body and comments for that post.

**What I'm trying to do**

Instead of just displaying the title and date of each post on the index page, I want to display a title, date and a short description of each post.

**What I did**

The original `new.html.erb` is a page to create new posts, and part of it looked like this:

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
<% end %>
```

So I added:

```
<%= f.text_field :description %>
```

My posts model:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

So, I added:

```
t.string :description
```

That did not work. So I tried to do this in terminal

```
$ rails g model Post title:string description:string body:text --force
```

That was even worse. Overall, I ended up with so many errors I just restarted the tutorial.

So, my question is: **"How can I add a description to my posts?"**

Comment: Once you create a model with a migration, you have two options to add a column to the model. a) as you did add `t.string :description` to the existing migration file and recreate the table by `rake db:migration:redo`. b) create a new migration with `add_column :posts, :description, :string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow below steps:

Step 1:Migration to add a new field using rails generator.

```
rails g migration add_description_to_posts
```

Step 2: In generated migration file:

```
class AddDescriptionsToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :description, :string        
  end
end
```

Step 3: Migrate datbase

```
rake db:migrate
```

Step 4:Change in view.

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :title %>
 <%= f.text_area :body %>
 <%= f.text_area :description %>
<% end %>
```

Step 5: In PostController.rb, add description in white list parameters:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :description)
end
```

Let me know if you face any difficulty.

Answer (score 4):

You do this by running a migration. Run `rails generate migration add_description_to_posts description:string`

Then run `rake db:migrate` to run the migration. You will then have a description column in your Posts table

To then add the description to the posts, you need to add the `:description` in the posts params in the post controller and add an input field in the posts form for the description.

To display the description you need to include the tag `<%= @post.description %>`

Answer (score 2):

You have two options to do:

**Option1**: You don't want to create `new migration file`

**step1**: You run `rake db:rollback`

**step2**: In your `migration file`, you add `t.string :description`

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :posts do |t|
     t.string :title
     t.string :description
     t.text :body

     t.timestamps
   end
  end
end
```

**step3**: You run `rake db:migrate`

**step4**: In your `new.html.erb`, you can do this:

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
<% end %>
```

**Option2**: You want to create `new migration file`

**step1**: You create `new migration file` to add `new column` to `your table`

```
rails generate migration add_description_to_posts description:string
```

**step2**: In your migration file which was created, you add new column

```
add_column :posts, :description, :string
```

**step3**: You run `rake db:migrate`

**step4**: In your `new.html.erb`, you can do this:

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
<% end %>
```